# Import google font but specific font weight is not included

Tags: css, fonts

I imported Rubik font using this code.

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik' rel='stylesheet'>
```

When I use *font-weight:500* or *font-weight:800*, etc working except *font-weight:500*

How can I do this?

Someone says importing default Rubik font family, will not import font-weight 500.

Anyhelp would be appreciate.

Comment: family or weight ? check well

Comment: or sorry font-weight

Comment: go directly to the link and you will see https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik

Comment: so should I include many css files? not only that font due to its font-weight normal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may try this link :

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik:500,500i' rel='stylesheet'>
```

By the way when you open the link `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik:500,500i` in your browser you can see the **styles** that are included.

And when you don't specify anything you will only get the regular one (font-weight:400)

All the possibilties for this font are : `300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i,900,900i`

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the required font-weights on your `link`'s `href` property. Such as `:500,800` to get font-weights 500 and 800.

[It seems Rubik does not support font-weight 800](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Rubik?selection.family=Rubik:500,700), so you're not going to be able to get it anyway. Instead you could use 700 or 900 fonts. So the value of `href` should be something like `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik:500,700`.

```css
div {
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik:500,700" rel="stylesheet">
<div style="font-weight: 500">
   Hello World!
</div>
<div style="font-weight: 700">
   Hello World!
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just import it with the font weights you want, for example:

`https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik:400i,700`

You have an option in [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/) to choose font weight:

[image: google fonts 1]

---

And after clicking:

[image: google fonts 2]